# What is the difference between 無感動 and 無関心?

Tags: word-choice

I know that both of them can be translated as “apathy”, but is there a distinction between them? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 3):

This 無 is a prefix meaning "-less". If you understand the difference between 感動 and 関心, the difference between 無感動 and 無関心 is almost self-evident. 関心 is "interest" or "curiosity", whereas 感動 is "(emotional) movement" or "excitement"

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I wasn't sure if it mattered which one you would use. But I guess it does.

Comment: You shd be aware that 無関心 is very commonly used (to mean “indifferent” or “uninterested”), but 無感動 is not common at all.

Comment: @MarcAdler According to BCCWJ, 無関心 is 10 times as common as 無感動, but there are 64 examples of 無感動, and that's not a small number.